# Validation failed for one or more entities error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

While saving the client name, it shows that the clientID is having as value null.
I tried much, but could not get the solution.
Here's the code :

Controller:

```
[SpecialAuthorize("Client_Add")]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var client = new OData.Client();
    client.Picture = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    SetMyBag(client);
    return View("Edit", client);
}

[HttpPost]
[SpecialAuthorize("Client_Add")]
public ActionResult Create(OData.Client model)
{
    var client = new OData.Client();
    if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
    {
        db.Clients.Add(client);
        db.SaveChanges();
        db.LogHistory(new Activity(ActionEnum.Created, model.ClientId, model.ResellerName, model.ClientId, "Client"));
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    SetMyBag(client);
    return View("Edit", model);
}
```

Comment: When the form is submitted from your "Edit" View..Does it hit your create[Post] ActionResult?

Comment: aritra : yes, it hits my PostActionResult.

Comment: @Iliya.Sullimanov : it always shows clientID as zero. What could it possibly be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got that.
I simply mistook and got the parameter wrong.

```
         [SpecialAuthorize("Client_Add")]
     public ActionResult Create(Model.Client model)
     {
       //var client = new Model.Client();
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
            db.Clients.Add(model);
             db.SaveChanges();
             db.LogHistory(new Activity(ActionEnum.Created, model.ClientId, model.ResellerName, model.ClientId, "Client"));
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
         }
        SetMyBag(model);
         return View("Edit", model);
     }
```